# do i need another HAT for using K210_7 Mic_v1.1 6+1 microphone array for RPI?

Tags: analog-to-digital, microphone

sorry for the novice question. but i could'nt find any specific information on my issue. so...

I got a cheap K210_7 Mic_v1.1 - 6+1 microphone circular array. and then i noticed that the respeaker version has a nother HAT that the mic array is connected through it.

do i need it?
why can't i connect trough I2C directly to the RPI?

Thanks.[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorpI.jpg)

Comment: Link to the product?

Comment: this is what i got - https://www.banggood.com/6+1-Microphone-Voice-Recognition-Array-I2S-Interface-Sound-Source-Localization-K210-Development-Board-Accessories-p-1683389.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN

this is the respaker product - https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_6-Mic_Circular_Array_kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/